# How to update database base on laravel checkbox value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, checkbox

I load check boxes from database with they are checked or not,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">

            @php
                $json = $orders->data;
                $json = json_decode($json, true);
                $products = $json['order_info']['products'];

                $data = '';

                    foreach ($products as $hitsIndex => $hitsValue) {
                        $data .= $hitsValue['type']. ', ';
                    }
                $data = rtrim($data, ', ');

                $agosProducts = Utility::constant('agos_products1');
            @endphp

            {{Html::validation($orders, 'product')}}
            <label for="products" class="control-label">{{Translator::transSmart('app.Products', 'Products')}}</label><br><br>

            @foreach($agosProducts as $product)

                <label class="control-label "for="{{ $product['type'] }}">
                    <input id="{{ $product['type'] }}" name="{{ $product['type'] }}" type="checkbox" value="{{ $product['type'] }}"
                           @foreach ($products as $hitsIndex => $hitsValue)
                                @if(in_array($hitsValue['type'], $product)) checked=checked @endif
                           @endforeach
                    >
                    {{ $product['name'] }}
                </label>
                <br>

            @endforeach

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i want to update my database base on checkbox value.

For example if say i load checkbox 1 as checked from database and now it's unchecked i need to update it in database.

This code i can get all the current status of checkbox but i don't know previous values of this. So it hard update statue of current values and add new status in database,

```
$chks = array('multicolor','resizable','showRuler','namesNumbersEnabled');
foreach ($chks as $chk) {
   $product->setAttribute($chk, (Input::has($chk)) ? true : false);
}
```

**This is my json object save in data column**

```
{"user_token":"ad48c412-3866-4ac9-adf6-3328911ae46c",
"order_info": 
{"order_id":"CGC12345678","company_id":32,"price":1000.5,"currency":"MYR",
"products":[
{"type":"HR_ECLAIM","name":"HREClaim","is_fixed_price":true,"price":500.5,"currency":"MYR"},
{"type":"HR_ELEAVE","name":"HRELeave","is_fixed_price":true,"price":500,"currency":"MYR"}
],
"total_invoices":200,"total_staffs":80},"url":"https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Is6QsnuMLu9ZIpqeEzR2O2Ve1wUyF92aVCg55kWsOgc"}
```

i load [order_info][products][type] as checked products in while i load all the products from env file. I only need to save checked check box products in db.

Can someone helps me?

Comment: You don't have to worry about the previous status of the checkbox while you are updating if some one saves the form then only selected values sets true in the database and all other will false.

Comment: So when you go to the same page those selected values should be shown as selected and other will not.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit in db checkbox 1 checked and checkbox 2 and check box 3 values are not in db because they haven't checked. During edit i made check box 2 also checked and made check box 1 unchecked. how i update this in db? Only need to save checkbx 2 values in db while removed check box 1 values from db

Comment: Then please be specific how you store the data in database ? is it in the JSON or in the columns.?

Comment: @DhavalPurohit i update question with json object

Comment: so the products `type` should be array or what? from json it is a string.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit array

Comment: Okay then why it is string in the JSON you have mentioned here?

Comment: @DhavalPurohit sry i didn't get it?

Comment: you are saying that product `type` attribute should save all the checkboxes true or false then why it is in the string as described in your JSON

Comment: @DhavalPurohit this is for one checkbox  checked. {"type":"HR_ECLAIM","name":"HREClaim","is_fixed_price":true,"price":500.5,"currency":"MYR"}. other details um getting from env file

Comment: if HR_ECLAIM unchecked above {} should be removed and if i checked FIN_REP new {} should save in db

Comment: {"type":"HR_ECLAIM","name":"HREClaim","is_fixed_price":true,"price":500.5,"currency":"MYR"} the type i used identify  it's checked or not in blade file

Comment: Okay @LearnwithPanda will give the solution after lunch break.

Comment: Okay @DhavalPurohit

Comment: as showing the whole code what i understand is you are adding and removing products on checkbox checked and removed so why don;t you just removed all what is before update and just add what is currently checked.

Comment: I mean to say just remove all products of that order_id before adding these new. `foreach ($chks as $chk) {
   $product->setAttribute($chk, (Input::has($chk)) ? true : false);
}`

Comment: because I am feeling that after this `for` loop you are also recalculating and adding other parameter of product used products attributes

Comment: @DhavalPurohit oky ill check and let u knw update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete working solution i done for my question!

```
public function edit($id, $attributes){

        $orders = (new Agos())->load($id);
        $json = $orders->data;
        $json = json_decode($json);

        $checkedit= $attributes['check_list'];

        if (is_array($checkedit) || is_object($checkedit))
        {
            foreach($checkedit as $chked1){

                $exists = false;
                foreach($json->products as $key => $val)
                {
                    // update if products exists
                    if($val->type == $chked1) {
                        $val->status = 'true';
                        $exists = true;
                    }

                    if(array_key_exists('status', $val)) {}
                    else{ $val->status = 'false';}

                }

                if($chked1 == 'FIN_REPORTING')
                {
                    $name = 'Finance reporting & book keeping';
                }
                elseif ($chked1 == 'FIN_ADVISORY')
                {
                    $name = 'Finance Advisory';
                }
                elseif ($chked1 == 'PAYROLL_HRDB')
                {
                    $name = 'PAYROLL_HRDB';
                }
                elseif ($chked1 == 'HR_ELEAVE')
                {
                    $name =   'HR E-Leave';
                }
                else
                {
                    $name = 'HR E-Claim';
                }

                //if products not exists add new products
                if(!$exists) {

                    $newproduct = new \stdClass();
                    $newproduct->type = $chked1;
                    $newproduct->name = $name;
                    $newproduct->is_fixed_price = false;
                    $newproduct->currency = "MYR";
                    $newproduct->status = "true";
                    array_push($json->products, $newproduct);
                }
            }
        }

        //remove all products that have status = false
        foreach($json->products as $index => $product) {
            if ( $product->status == "false") {
                unset($json->products[$index]);
            }
        }
        $json->products = array_values($json->products);
        json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


        //remove status element from products
        foreach($json->products as $index => $product) {

                unset($product->status);

        }
        $json->products = array_values($json->products);
        json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

        $json->google_drive_url= $attributes['data'];
        $json->remark= $attributes['remark'];
        $json->status= $attributes['status'];
        $json->total_invoices= $attributes['total_invoices'];
        $json->total_staffs= $attributes['total_staffs'];
        $json1 = json_encode($json);

        $status = $attributes['status'];
        $total_price = str_replace(',','', $attributes['total_price']);

        DB::table('orders')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update(['data' => $json1,'status' => $status, 'price' => $total_price]);

    }
```